# Breaking apart a fraction in an expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are random variables that are correlated, and can only have values in some range $[0,R]$. I would like to lower bound $\mathbb E[A/B]$ the expected value of $A/B$.

I have a concentration bound that says $B < \mathbb E[B] + \epsilon$ with probability $1-\delta$. I would now like to conclude something like

$$\mathbb E\left[\frac{A}{B}\right] \geq \frac{\mathbb E[A]}{\mathbb E[B]+\epsilon}$$

as long as $\delta$ is small enough. Does this line of argument make sense? Does the correlation between $A$ and $B$ make this reasoning not logical?

Also, does there exist a $\delta > 0$ small enough such that this implication holds? I suspect we can concoct an adversarial case where with probability $\delta$, $B = R$. But I'm not sure how it affects things because of the fraction. Any hints?

Comment: If, for example, $B=\Bbb E[B]+\epsilon$ with probability $1-\delta$, and $A$ takes the value $0$ whenever $B\ne\Bbb E[B]+\epsilon$, then I don't think one can get a better lower bound than $(1-\delta)\Bbb E[A]/(\Bbb E[B]+\epsilon)$. Would that be good enough for you?

Comment: Yes! That would be great! So to make sure I got the whole thing, are you just using law of total expectation, eg. $ \mathbb E[A/B | B > \mathbb E[B]+\epsilon] (1-\delta) +  \mathbb E[A/B|B<  \mathbb E[B] + \epsilon]\delta >  \mathbb E[A/(\mathbb E[B]+\epsilon)] (1-\delta) $?

Comment: Thank you! I think that hint did it!

Comment: A colleague of mine found a bug with this analysis. What if $\mathbb E[A] = 100$, for example, but $\mathbb E[A|B > \mathbb E[B]+\epsilon] = -100$, which could happen. We can't negate what happens because of the conditioning...

Comment: The OP says that $A$ can't take negative values. Certainly if negative values are in play, all bets are off.

Comment: right, sorry, amend scenario to if $\mathbb E[A|B<\mathbb E[B]+\epsilon] = 0$. The idea being the conditioning really screws with you.

Comment: I have to think about this a bit longer... it might still be reparable, but maybe we need a more rigorous proof.